# Use Validate presence of conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two different types of sign_up,
"normal user" and "set user"  both having a different fields and different validation but
refers to one table only.

How will I check a validation condition for them, 
For eg:

```
  validates_presence_of :first_name,
```

should check a validation while signup as "normal user" and not for  "set user"
and "account_type" which differentiate them is in different table, so I am not able to user

```
 validates_presence_of :first_name,:if=> Proc.new{|user| user.user_info.account_type !='set'}
```

And it's before saving into database,
how will I check a condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your answer but may be you could use a callback,
before_add or before_create in the user model.

```
See the api:
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Check before_validation function also.

```
before_validation(:on => :create) do
   # code check here...
end
```